# FileWriter doesn't write to file even after .flush()/.close()

Tags: java, filewriter

I am trying to write to a text file but even though the method creates the file if it does not exist, it does not write. I have been through several other posts with a similar issue and followed the advice but had no luck.

Through use of the debugger, the String data contains the correct data that should be written but it is never written to the text file.

Any advice on something I've overlooked would be appreciated.

```
private static void createReservation(String filmName, String date, int noOfSeats, String username) {
    FileWriter fw = null;
    try {
        File bookingFile = new File("C:\\server\\bookinginfo.txt");
        if (!bookingFile.exists())
        {
            bookingFile.createNewFile();
        }
        fw = new FileWriter(bookingFile.getName(),true);
        String data = "<"+filmName+"><"+date+"><"+Integer.toString(noOfSeats)+"><"+username+">\r\n";
        fw.write(data);
        fw.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FilmInfoHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FilmInfoHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any exceptions in your logs? Can you definitely write to that file?

Comment: No exceptions are thrown at all. Not too sure how to tell if I can write to that file specifically, but in another area of my project, the program creates and writes to two separate XML files located in the same directory.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Got it - this is the problem:

```
new FileWriter(bookingFile.getName(),true);
```

The `getName()` method will just return `bookinginfo.txt`, which means it'll be creating a file called `bookinginfo.txt` in the current working directory.

Just use the constructor which takes a `File`:

```
fw = new FileWriter(bookingFile, true);
```

Also note that you don't need to call `createNewFile()` first - the `FileWriter` constructor will create the file if it doesn't exist.

As an aside, I'm personally not a fan of `FileWriter` - it *always* uses the platform default encoding. I would recommend using `FileOutputStream` wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter` where you can specify the encoding. Or use the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) helper methods which make all of this somewhat simpler. For example:

```
Files.append(bookingFile, data, Charsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. New to Java so couldn't see that myself. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
fw = new FileWriter(bookingFile.getAbsolutePath(),true);
```

instead of

```
fw = new FileWriter(bookingFile.getName(),true);
```